# Behaviour of program modified by strncpy

Tags: c, string, strncpy

Consider,

```
int main()
{
 char s[10];
 strncpy(s,"hello",5);
 printf("Hello !!%s %d\n",s,strlen(s));
 return 0;
}
```

When I run this program nothing is printed. But when I comment the call to strncpy, it prints "Hello !! 0".

Used ideone ("http://ideone.com/j1cdKp")

when I used the gcc compiler (Debian 7.4), it gave the expected output ("Hello !!hello 6").

Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

-Newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1

This code causes undefined behavior because you try to print a string `s` that is uninitialized.

```
char s[10];
printf("Hello!! %s %d\n",s,strlen(s));
```

### Part 2

This code causes undefined behavior because you try to print a string that is not null terminated. `strncpy` with the arguments given will copy "hello", but will not copy the trailing null terminator.

```
char s[10];
strncpy(s,"hello",5);
printf("Hello!! %s %d\n",s,strlen(s));
```

### Part 3

The following code is correct. Note that the argument to `strncpy` is **`6`**.

```
char s[10];
strncpy(s,"hello",6);
printf("Hello!! %s %d\n",s,strlen(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program causes undefined behaviour.  `s` is uninitalized, and `strncpy(s,"hello",5);` doesn't copy enough characters to include the null terminator.